# Developing Unity Game VR and non-VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, real-time-multiplayer

I'm new to Unity and I am confused about how to develop a game for both VR and FPS-desktop at the same time. How can I handle this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[this article](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/VROverview.html#:%7E:text=Unity%20VR%20lets%20you%20target,for%20future%20devices%20and%20software.) about VR inm Unity can help you.
The good thing about Unity is that you can develop one game and deploy it on multiple diffrent plattforms without major changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, you should make progress one by one, step by step.

1. IDE select
   You should select the correct IDE like Unity, Unreal Engine, C++ or some others you'd like to develop with.
2. Non-VR Development
   As you are new to Unity, you should handle Non-VR games first (like FPS game) thanks to Unity Tutorials or Learning Courses.
3. Get Familiar with Unity Game Development
   As you make progress with tutorials, you should be able to get familiar with Unity Game Development.
4. VR Integration
   You can study VR like Step 3
5. VR and Non-VR FPS at the same time
   When developing a game for both VR and FPS-desktop platforms simultaneously, the key is to design your game architecture to be flexible and modular. This approach allows you to share core game logic across both platforms while customizing input, user interface, and certain gameplay elements to suit the unique requirements of VR and desktop environments.

Hope this could help you make projects well.
Best Regards